# Why do desktop GPUs typically use immediate mode rendering instead of tile based deferred rendering?

Tags: gpu

In other words, what are the advantages of immediate mode rendering vs. TBDR, assuming you have ample memory, bandwidth, and power (as found on a desktop GPU)?

Comment: I'm just curious in which course this homework question was asked.

Comment: Not a homework question. I've been reading about the advantages of TBDR on GPUs, and I'm having trouble finding a discussion about the opposite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main drawback of TBDRs is that they struggle with large amounts of geometry, because they sort it before rendering in order to achieve zero overdraw. This is not a huge deal on low-power GPUs because they deal with simpler scenes anyway.

Modern desktop GPUs do have early-z tests, so if you sort the geometry and draw it front-to-back you can still get most of the bandwidth minimization of a TBDR, and many non-deferred mobile GPUs still do tiling even if they don't sort the geometry.